# Why is Byobu is only registering some bind keys?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux, byobu

This is the contents of my keybindings.tmux file:
This file works completely on a mac and I'm trying to get the same binding for my linux machine.

# Add F12 to the prefix list

```
# Clear the slate
source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable

# Byobu's Keybindings
# Documented in: $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/doc/byobu/help.tmux.txt
bind-key -n F1 new-window -k -n config byobu-config
bind-key -n S-F1 new-window -k -n help '$BYOBU_PAGER $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/doc/byobu/help.tmux.txt'
bind-key -n F2 new-window \; rename-window "-"

#bind-key -n C-F2 display-panes \; split-window -h
#bind-key -n S-F2 display-panes \; split-window -v
bind-key -n M-v display-panes \; split-window -h
bind-key -n M-h display-panes \; split-window -v

bind-key -n C-S-F2 new-session
bind-key -n F3 previous-window
bind-key -n F4 next-window
bind-key -n M-Left previous-window
bind-key -n M-Right next-window
bind-key -n M-Up switch-client -p
bind-key -n M-Down switch-client -n
bind-key -n S-F3 display-panes \; select-pane -t :.-
bind-key -n S-F4 display-panes \; select-pane -t :.+

#bind-key -n S-Up display-panes \; select-pane -U
#bind-key -n S-Down display-panes \; select-pane -D
#bind-key -n S-Left display-panes \; select-pane -L
#bind-key -n S-Right display-panes \; select-pane -R
#
# Use Vi(m) bindings for switching panes with ^<char>
bind-key -n C-S-i display-panes \; select-pane -U
bind-key -n C-S-k display-panes \; select-pane -D
bind-key -n C-S-j display-panes \; select-pane -L
bind-key -n C-S-l display-panes \; select-pane -R

bind-key -n C-F3 display-panes \; swap-pane -s :. -t :.- \; select-pane -t :.-
bind-key -n C-F4 display-panes \; swap-pane -s :. -t :.+ \; select-pane -t :.+
bind-key -n C-S-F3 swap-window -t :-1
bind-key -n C-S-F4 swap-window -t :+1

bind-key -n M-S-Up resize-pane -U
bind-key -n M-S-Down resize-pane -D
bind-key -n M-S-Left resize-pane -L
bind-key -n M-S-Right resize-pane -R

# Use Vim bindings for resizing panes with Shift+Alt+<char>
#bind-key -n M-S-k resize-pane -U
#bind-key -n M-S-j resize-pane -D
#bind-key -n M-S-l resize-pane -L
#bind-key -n M-S-h resize-pane -R

bind-key -n F5 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc
bind-key -n M-F5 run-shell '$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/toggle-utf8' \; source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc
bind-key -n S-F5 new-window -k "$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/cycle-status" \; source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc
bind-key -n C-F5 send-keys ". $BYOBU_PREFIX/bin/byobu-reconnect-sockets" \; send-keys Enter
bind-key -n C-S-F5 new-window -d "byobu-select-profile -r"
bind-key -n F6 detach
bind-key -n M-F6 run-shell '$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client'
bind-key -n S-F6 run-shell 'exec touch $BYOBU_RUN_DIR/no-logout' \; detach
bind-key -n C-F6 kill-pane
bind-key -n F7 copy-mode
bind-key -n S-F7 capture-pane -S -32768 \; save-buffer "$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen" \; delete-buffer \; new-window -n "PRINTSCREEN" "view $BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen"
bind-key -n M-NPage copy-mode \; send-keys NPage
bind-key -n M-PPage copy-mode \; send-keys PPage
bind-key -n F8 command-prompt -p "(rename-window) " "rename-window '%%'"
bind-key -n C-F8 command-prompt -p "(rename-session) " "rename-session '%%'"
bind-key -n S-F8 next-layout
bind-key -n M-S-F8 new-window -k "byobu-layout restore; clear; $SHELL"
bind-key -n C-S-F8 command-prompt -p "Save byobu layout as:" "run-shell \"byobu-layout save '%%'\""
bind-key -n F9 new-window -k -n config byobu-config
bind-key -n S-F9 command-prompt -p "Send command to all panes:" "run-shell \"$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/tmux-send-command-to-all-panes '%%'\""
bind-key -n C-F9 command-prompt -p "Send command to all windows:" "run-shell \"$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/tmux-send-command-to-all-windows '%%'\""
bind-key -n M-F9 display-panes \; setw synchronize-panes
bind-key -n M-F11 break-pane
bind-key -n C-F11 join-pane -h -s :. -t :-1
bind-key -n S-F11 resize-pane -Z
bind-key -n S-F12 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux.disable \; display-message "Byobu F-keys: DISABLED"
bind-key -n C-S-F12 new-window $BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/mondrian
bind-key -n M-F12 source $BYOBU_PREFIX/share/byobu/keybindings/mouse.tmux.enable
bind-key -n M-IC paste-buffer

bind-key -n C-a new-window -n "ctrl-a" "byobu-ctrl-a"

#set -g prefix F12
#unbind-key -n C-a
set -g prefix F12
unbind-key -n C-a
```

specifically this keys

```
# Use Vi(m) bindings for switching panes with ^<char>
bind-key -n C-S-i display-panes \; select-pane -U
bind-key -n C-S-k display-panes \; select-pane -D
bind-key -n C-S-j display-panes \; select-pane -L
bind-key -n C-S-l display-panes \; select-pane -R
```

Any help is appreciated. Disclaimer: I took most of the keybindings from this guy: https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux